# Sum the elements in an array until its divisible by 5 and continue the same in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, while-loop

Please help me get the logic in python
Input is sample= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Excepted output is
Result=[15,40]
Explanation
checks each element in sample and adds one by one until the value is divisible by 5 (so 1+2+3+4+5=15)
And the check and add continues (so 6+7+8+9+10=40) thus the result is in list result =[15,40]

I tried
For i in sample
If(sample[i] % 5==0):
But it is not continuing after the conditions

Comment: 1+2+3+4=10 which is also divisible by 5. Why not stop there?

Comment: Unclear but it seems that "when the VALUE is divisible by 5" means the last added value (not the sum itself)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Reinderien the value will be different like (12,13,14,15,16,17) so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help:

```
sample = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
result = []
current_sum = 0

for num in sample:
    current_sum += num
    if num % 5 == 0:
        result.append(current_sum)
        current_sum = 0

if current_sum != 0:
    result.append(current_sum)

print(result)
```

Comment: With a list like `sample = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]` this produces `[15, 34]`. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: No, this will produce `[15,40]`

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to identify the indexes of values that are divisible by 5 and use sum() on the ranges between them:

```
sample = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

idx    = [i for i,n in enumerate(sample,1) if n%5 == 0]
result = [sum(sample[s:e]) for s,e in zip([0]+idx,idx)]

print(result)
[15, 40]
```

Comment: Unknown, no other example provided.  It does follow the rule as I understood it.

Comment: Fair enough...rereading the question, I see your point.